# Django url conf

Tags: django-urls, django-login

When user logs in, he is redirected to /accounts/loggedin/ . Loggedin is the simple view that renders logged_in.html template which has menu on it.
Example of the menu item:

```
<li><a id="n-rsvp" href="rsvp/" title=""></a></li>
```

Rsvp is the app I created. The question is what should I put inside of template so after clicking on RSVP on the menu user redirects to the "global" rsvp url, so instead of looking like this:
     http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/loggedin/rsvp
url should be looking like this
     http://127.0.0.1:8000/rsvp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my first guess would be `href="/rsvp/"`

Comment: the strange thing is - when i edit, save and re-reload template no changes appears.. why?